# How can I speed up this loop?

Tags: matlab

I have a huge matrix (5000x5000x100) and I'm trying to smooth each index along the third dimension, but it takes HOURS. I am doing something inefficiently.

```
new_mat=zeros(size(my_mat));
for i = 1:length(mymat)
   for j = 1:length(mymat)
      new_mat(i,j,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymat(i,j,:)));
   end
end
```

I know arrays and indexing would help but I'm not sure how to apply them here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you profile your code? Possibly the `wdenoise` call takes the most time, as loops are highly optimised since 2016b.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I made a typo when writing the question- I used size to proallocate. I'll edit the question, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the newer Wavelet Toolbox needed for wdenoise, but since the function will operate across columns if you provide a matrix you should be able to remove the inner loop which may increase the speed a bit:

```
new_mat=zeros(my_mat)
for i = 1:length(mymat)
    new_mat(i,:,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymat(i,:,:)));
end
```